# React | Multiple render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I just want to know if there is any way I can "draw" in my `index.html` multiple `<div id = "x" /> <div id = "y" />` with REACT, i mean.. i have all my site on `index.html` with all my template, so i only need to use REACT on an specifics sections...

[image]

i tried this i didnt work

> HTML

```
<div id="test" />
<div id="app" />
<script src="public/bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

> JSX

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (<h1>App</h1>);
  }
}
class Test extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (<h1>Test</h1>);
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('test'));
```

then when i load the page only prints the `<h1>Test</h1>`... why?

Comment: Try closing your div tags.  Div is not self-closing.

Comment: i tried, but nothing!

Comment: Are you using the dev version of React?  If so, you should be getting some helpful errors in the console.

Comment: how do i know if im using dev version?

Comment: You cannot do `return (
     <div>1</div>
     <div>2</div>
    );` place them within a parent div, like `return (
     <div>
       <div>1</div>
       <div>2</div>
     </div>
    );`, What do you see in the `developer console`?

Comment: You'd get an error message in the console.  @Random User is totally right.

Comment: wrap your `App` component in a div as `<div><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>`

Comment: check my edit..

Comment: I've done this successfully - Can't see what's wrong from looking at your code, are you able to make a Plunkr or CodePen that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @MattHolland look at this screenshots...html: http://prntscr.com/ciuip9 || jsx: http://prntscr.com/ciuj18 || browser: http://prntscr.com/ciujhq

Comment: Is that your whole HTML document? I'm guessing a little here, but what if you have a "well formed" HTML page (With <html> and <body> tags)?

Comment: @MattHolland   Yes, but i was testing with a simple code because with the real page it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a JSFiddle to try a few things out here: http://jsfiddle.net/pof580fd/1/

I found out that by explicitly closing each of the `<div>` tags I could get it to work, i.e.:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I did a little research and it appears that as `div` is not one of the HTML5 "void elements" (Listed here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) it is not self-closing and you must use `</div>`. See this SO question for more details: [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Possibly some browsers are lenient about this (I'm using Chrome 52 right now) - but React is not, it appears. The error message I see in the console is:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

(Make sure you're using the "dev" version of React to see these)

Comment: Thanks you! so its the self-closing in the html.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new component and call from that.

```
import App from "./App";
import Test from "./Test";
class Program extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <div id="app"><App /></div>
      <div id="test"><Test /></div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

and then call

```
render(<Program />), document.getElementById('...'));
```

Comment: is not what I need, I know it can be done that way but still do render a single div in my html...check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

We created a framework to do this with great success.

Have a look at [React Habitat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-habitat).

With it you can just register components eg:

```
container.register('SomeReactComponent', SomeReactComponent);
```

Then they auto resolve in the dom via:

```
<div data-component="SomeReactComponent"></div>
```